# Making a cross-platform build of JavaFX using Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, javafx

I'm working on a new project using Gradle and JavaFX.
I have previously been able to create a cross-platform build using Maven, with the following pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

How do i go about doing something similar with Gradle?
I have tried the following, with no success.
Is the classifier syntax incorrect?

```
compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: '11.0.2:win'
compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: '11.0.2:linux'
compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: '11.0.2:mac'
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the jar with dependencies under the "cross-platform build"?

Answer (score 2):

The solution turned out to be the following gradle build dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-fxml', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-fxml', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-fxml', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'
```

This allows a javafx gradle build to be run on any OS.

Comment: What about Apple Silicon vs Intel chips?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is indeed incorrect in Gradle. [Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html) will show you the different supported syntax.

The two most common are the map style you used and the `:` separated notation.

So taking one of your dependency as an example, you need to use either:

- `compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: '11.0.2', classifier: 'win'`
- `compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11.0.2:win'`

Note that you should also stop using the `compile` configuration and instead use `implementation`. See [this explanation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) to understand more on this topic.